# Awk split by delimiter and take first entry

Tags: awk

I have an input like so:

```
chr1    28374C       T       0.0     PASS    AF=0.730769;AO=19;DP=26;
chr1    29631A       G       0.0     PASS    AF=0.6;AO=6;DP=10;
chr1    39322CAC    ACC      0.0     PASS    AF=0.266667,0.266667;AO=4,4;DP=16;
```

I want to take the first AF=[0-9].
I have managed to split the column by ";" but I don't know how to only take the first entry. So I have used awk:

```
cat file | awk '{split($6,a,";"); print a[1]}'
```

which gives:

```
AF=0.730769
AF=0.6
AF=0.266667,0.266667
```

but I only want:

```
AF=0.730769
AF=0.6
AF=0.266667
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Awk's `split` function takes a regular expression as the separator, so you can use a regular expression that includes both `;` and `,`:

```
awk '{split($6,a,/[;,]/); print a[1]}' file
```

(no need for `cat` and `|`). You could also split twice, using distinct separators:

```
awk '{split($6,a,/;/); split(a[1],b,/,/); print b[1]}' file
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$ awk -F'[[:space:],;]+' '{print $6}' file
AF=0.730769
AF=0.6
AF=0.266667
```