# awk split column by delimiter

Tags: awk

I nearly have the answer from here [Awk split by delimiter and take first entry](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/662903/awk-split-by-delimiter-and-take-first-entry/662906?noredirect=1#comment1246929_662906)
But need the final help.
I have a file:

```
chr1    283 C       T       0.0     PASS    AF=0.730769;AO=19;DP=26;FAO=19;FDP=26;FDVR=5;FR=.;FRO=7;FSAF=12;FSAR=7;
chr1    296 A       G       0.0     PASS    AF=0.6;AO=6;DP=10;FAO=6;FDP=10;FDVR=10;FR=.;FRO=4;FSAF=3;FSAR=3;
chr1    393 CACA    ACCA    0.0     PASS    AF=0.266667,0.266667;AO=4,4;DP=16;FAO=4,4;FDP=15;FDVR=5,5;FR=.,.,.,.,HEALED,HEALED;FRO=2;FSAF=0,0;FSAR=4,4;
```

I need to split the final column on ";" then "," and extract various parts.
I would like to extract the AF, FSAF and FSAR entries and where there are double entries take the first one.
I have the following but this may not be the best way (and I haven't worked out how to do this all on the same line):

```
awk '{split($13,a,/;/); split(a[1],b,/,/); print b[1]}'

awk '{split($13,a,/;/); split(a[9],c,/,/); print c[1]}'

awk '{split($13,a,/;/); split(a[10],d,/,/); print d[1]}'
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question to state **what** you want to do rather than **how** you're trying to do it. Those awk/split commands may not be the best way to do what you want individually, never mind trying to combine them. Also add the expected output given that input. Make sure your code matches your example by the way - your code is trying to split the 13th field but your example only has 7 fields.

Comment: Apologies again Ed!

Comment: No problem. Asking a good question is often harder than answering a good question.

Comment: You say "where there are double entries take the first one" - A) do you mean double entries on each line or across the whole file? B) where do such double entries occur in your sample input? Please [edit] your question to clarify and remember to add the expected output given your posted sample input. You're providing an example we can copy/paste to test a potential solution against and having input without output or vice-versa is only half what we need to do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question isn't entirely clear (see my comments under it) but, assuming by "where there are double entries take the first one" you mean duplicate `FOO=bar` entries on each line, I think this might be what you're trying to do (using any awk in any shell on every Unix box):

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { OFS=";" }
{
    delete f
    n = split($7,subFlds,/;/)
    for (i=1; i<=n; i++) {
        tag = val = subFlds[i]
        sub(/=.*/,"",tag)
        sub(/,.*/,"",val)
        if ( !(tag in f) ) {
            f[tag] = val
        }
    }
    print f["AF"], f["FSAF"], f["FSAR"]
}
```

```
$ awk -f tst.awk file
AF=0.730769;FSAF=12;FSAR=7
AF=0.6;FSAF=3;FSAR=3
AF=0.266667;FSAF=0;FSAR=4
```

Obviously you can change the output separator, `OFS`, to be whatever you like if that's not formatted as you want.

Whenever you have tag=value pairs in your data as you do, if you first create an array of the tags (aka names) to values mappings (`f[]` above) then you can just print/test/modify/whatever the values by their tags however you like in whatever order you like.

Note that the above will work even if the tags don't always appear in the same order in the input or some tags could be missing from some rows, etc.

Comment: Thanks Ed, would you be able to explain line by line if you have time? (as am newbie and think awk is really handy so want to learn as much as I can). I understand  the 'n' part. For the tag are you saying replace anything after the '=' with nothing (which makes sense to me) then are you saying for value replace everything after the ',' with nothing? So for the third line value will be AF=0.266667? I don't understand where you create the dict? 'f'? I assume from this you can do this on the fly?

Comment: Correct all around. Sounds like you understood it perfectly but do let me know if you have any other questions. To learn AWK get the book Effective AWK Programming, 5th Edition, by Arnold Robbins.