# Get all keys from VCF file's info field

Tags: awk

This question is related to the previously answered - [Awk split by delimiter and take first entry](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/662903/awk-split-by-delimiter-and-take-first-entry) -

For a VCF file, which is a tab-separated format:

```
chr1    28374C       T       0.0     PASS    AF=0.730769;AO=19;DP=26;
chr1    29631A       G       0.0     PASS    AF=0.6;AO=6;DP=10;ALLELEID=1396033;
chr1    39322CAC    ACC      0.0     PASS    AF=0.266667,0.266667;AO=4,4;DP=16;
```

I would like to get the following output:

```
AF
AO
DP
AF
AO
DP
ALLELEID
AF
AO
DP
```

The `awk '{split($6,a,/;/); split(a[1],b,/=/); print b[1]}' file` gets all AF entries (as expected), but I'm unsure how to pull in the rest of the keys. How do I pass the whole of `a` in the second split?

Comment: Do you actually have a VCF file? What you show is not a valid VCF. VCFs are tab-separated, have a minimum of 8 fields per line and the INFO field is actually field number 8, not 6.

Comment: In addition to [terdon's comment](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/736216/get-all-keys-from-vcf-files-info-field#comment1397983_736216), VCF files usually come with an abundance of header lines.

Comment: Exactly, and in order for the file to be valid, every info field has a corresponding `##INFO` header, making it much easier to collect the fields from the headers.

Comment: @terdon: Yes, I am working with a fully-realized VCF file. The solution chosen below doesn't change except for picking the correct column number (8 vs 6). I chose to focus on the specific extraction-related issue while posting the question here.

Comment: @Abhi it does change though: if you need to be able to handle arbitrary files, you _must_ use `-F '\t'` to set awk's field separator to tab (INFO fields can contain whitespace in VCF files since version 4.3) and you'll also want to skip the header lines. By the way, you might be interested in our sister site: [bioinformatics.se].

Comment: Thanks for the link to the bioinformatics site, @terdon! My VCF file is gzipped; so my command line started with zcat <file.vcf.gz> | grep -v '^#' | awk -f8 . The problem wasn't getting until here; its what came after.

Comment: I know, but you really want something like `zgrep -v '^#' file.vcf.gz | awk -F'\t' '{print $8}'` to deal with whitespace in the INFO field (and we might as well avoid using two commands where one, `zgrep`, would do).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

##### Let's simplify with one pipe to [gnu](/questions/tagged/gnu) [grep](/questions/tagged/grep):

```
$ awk '{print $6 | "grep -oP \042[A-Z]+(?==)\042"}' file
```

or

```
$ awk '{print $6}' file | grep -oP '[A-Z]+(?==)'
AF
AO
DP
AF
AO
DP
ALLELEID
ID
AF
AO
DP
```

##### The regular expression matches as follows:

| Node | Explanation |
| --- | --- |
| `[A-Z]+` | any character of: 'A' to 'Z' (1 time or more) |
| `(?=` | [look ahead](https://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=518444) to see if there is: |
| `=` | = |
| `)` | end of look-ahead |

Comment: Thanks, Gilles. I changed your script to [A-Z]{1,}(?==) to include keys that are greater than 2 in length to allow ALLELEID to be included in the output.

Comment: @Abhi this will _not_ work on an actual VCF file. It works fine in the example you gave, but that example isn't a VCF file. Are you _sure_ that is what you have?

Comment: You should comment OP question @terdon

Comment: I have. But I also wanted to leave a comment here in the accepted answer because this wouldn't work on an actual VCF file so if someone else comes looking for a VCF solution they might be confused. I am not implying you did anything wrong, Gilles, your answer, which I upvoted, is really good for the data given in the question! I just happen to be very familiar with this particular file format since I work with it every day, which means I am aware of some traps that the OP might not know.

Comment: Maybe that require to edit original question to remove VCF if no response from OP

Answer (score 5):

Using any POSIX awk:

```
$ awk -F'[[:space:]=;]+' '{for (i=6; i<NF; i+=2) print $i}' file
AF
AO
DP
AF
AO
DP
ALLELEID
AF
AO
DP
```

Answer (score 4):

Using any awk:

```
$ awk '{ n=split($6, tmp, /=[^;]*;/); for(i=1; i<n; i++) print tmp[i] }' infile
AF
AO
DP
AF
AO
DP
ALLELEID
AF
AO
DP
```

or similarly with below to split the 6<sup>th</sup> column on either  characters `;` or `=` in one split() call:

```
awk '{ n=split($6, tmp, /[=;]/); for(i=1; i<n; i+=2) print tmp[i] }' infile
```

you then also can print the key's value too as:

```
$ awk '{n=split($6, tmp, /[=;]/); for(i=1; i<n; i+=2) print tmp[i], tmp[i+1] }' infile
AF 0.730769
AO 19
DP 26
AF 0.6
AO 6
DP 10
ALLELEID 1396033
AF 0.266667,0.266667
AO 4,4
DP 16
```

Answer (score 0):

Using any awk and also tr command:

```
$ awk '{print $6}' infile | tr "=" ";" | awk -F";" '{for (i=1;i<NF;i++) {if(i%2){print $i}}}'
AF
AO
DP
AF
AO
DP
ALLELEID
AF
AO
DP
```